# ¿Cómo traducir las filas de texto frances y árabe de las columnas al inglés?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero traducir la columna de una dataframe que esta en frances y arabo:

```
0                                       Chef de projet
                                                   ...
6                                           professeur
7                                       Chef de projet
8                                           مدير  شركة
```

Intenté:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['new_professionactuelle']= df['new_professionactuelle'].apply(translator.translate)
```

Pero obtengo

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-90b46ab0043a> in <module>
      1 from googletrans import Translator
      2 translator = Translator()
----> 3 df['new_professionactuelle']= df['new_professionactuelle'].apply(translator.translate)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
    170 
    171         origin = text
--> 172         data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
    173 
    174         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src)
     73             text = text.decode('utf-8')
     74 
---> 75         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
     76         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
     77                                     token=token)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in do(self, text)
    199     def do(self, text):
    200         self._update()
--> 201         tk = self.acquire(text)
    202         return tk

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in acquire(self, text)
    144         a = []
    145         # Convert text to ints
--> 146         for i in text:
    147             val = ord(i)
    148             if val < 0x10000:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto pasa en principio porque tienes valores `None` en la columna a traducir, basta con que filtres estos valores (también los posibles `NaN`) con `pandas.notnull` antes de llamar a `translator.translate(texto)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from googletrans import Translator


df = pd.DataFrame({'new_professionactuelle': (None,
                                              np.NaN,
                                              'Chef de projet',
                                              'professeur',
                                              'Chef de projet',
                                      'مدير  شركة'
                 )})   


translator = Translator() 

def translate(text):
    if pd.notnull(text):
        return translator.translate(text).text
    else:
        return text

df['new_professionactuelle'] = df['new_professionactuelle'].apply(translate)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>   new_professionactuelle
> 0                   None
> 1                    NaN
> 2        Project Manager
> 3              professor
> 4        Project Manager
> 5        company manager
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias para su respuesta! Sin embargo me devuelve un `JSONDecodError` al traducir. Espero que estés bien.

Comment: Hola, ¿el error se produce con mi ejemplo también o solo en tu caso real? Puedes editar la pregunta añadiendo el nuevo error (y el código que lo produce si no es el de la pregunta o mi ejemplo) a ver si podemos dar con lo que pasa. Un saludo.